# Unmet dependencies with gdevilspie

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to install gdevilspie_0.5-3.2_all.deb, but am getting error messages.

I need gdevilspie to be able to open a minimized mate-terminal window
like I can do with UM 18.04.

Can someone please help me.

```
andy@7_~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./gdevilspie_0.5-3.2_all.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gdevilspie' instead of './gdevilspie_0.5-3.2_all.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdevilspie : Depends: python-wnck but it is not installable
              Depends: python-glade2 but it is not installable
              Recommends: python-xdg but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdevilspie relies on PyGTK2, and with the removal of most Python 2 packages in current distributions, old gdevilspie packages are no longer installable.

It may be possible to install your package if you find packages for the dependencies (*e.g.* on [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org/)), if there are no conflicts with current Python packages on your system.

devilspie itself is still available, and installable directly in your distribution (*e.g.* `sudo apt install devilspie`). You can thus still write rules and have them applied to windows; you just won’t have the GUI provided by gdevilspie.